# What's the Ruby equivalent of Python `itertools.chain`?

Tags: ruby

Python's itertools module provides a lots of goodies with respect to processing an iterable/iterator by use of generators. What's the Ruby equivalent of Python [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)?

Comment: You might want to explain what `itertools.chain` does - not every Ruby expert knows Python.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt It produces an iterator that sequentially chains two or more existing iterators, i.e. produces values from one iterator until its exhaustion, then from the other, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a Ruby programmer, but I think something like this should do it:

```
def chain(*iterables)
   for it in iterables
       if it.instance_of? String
           it.split("").each do |i|
               yield i
           end
       else
           for elem in it
               yield elem
           end
       end
   end
end

chain([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9]], 'abc') do |x|
    print x
    puts
end
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
[7, 8, 9]
a
b
c
```

If you don't want to flatten strings, then using [`Array#flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten) this can be shortened to:

```
def chain(*iterables)
    return iterables.flatten(1) # not an iterator though
end
print chain([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9]], 'abc')
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9], "abc"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby equivalent of a Python iterator is an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html). There is no method for chaining two `Enumerator`s, but one can easily be written like so:

```
class Enumerator
  def chain(*others)
    self.class.new do |y|
      [clone, *others.map(&:clone)].each do |e|
        loop do y << e.next end
      end
    end
  end

  def +(other)
    chain(other)
  end
end

e1 = %w[one two].each
e2 = %w[three four].each
e3 = %w[five six].each

e = e1.chain(e2, e3)

e.map(&:upcase)
# => ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX']
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python docs for itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until
>   it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the
>   iterables are exhausted. Used for treating consecutive sequences as a
>   single sequence.

First, an example in Python

```
from itertools import chain

# nested arrays
iterables = [
                ["one", "two"], 
                ["three", "four"], 
                ["five", "six", "6", ["eight", "nine", "ten"]]
            ]

list(chain(*iterables))
```

Output:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', '6', ['eight', 'nine', 'ten']]
```

I am learning Ruby, so I tried to replicate the behavior using the code example from the Python docs:

```
# taken from Python docs as a guide
def chain(*iterables):
    # chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F
    for it in iterables:
        for element in it:
            yield element  # NOTE! `yield` in Python is not `yield` in Ruby. 
            # for simplicity's sake think of this `yield` as `return`
```

My Ruby code:

```
def chain(*iterables)
  items = []
  iterables.each do |it|
    it.each do |item|
      items << item
     end
  end
  items
end

nested_iterables = [%w[one two], %w[three four], %W[five six #{3 * 2}]]
nested_iterables[2].insert(-1, %w[eight nine ten])

puts chain(*nested_iterables)  

# and to enumerate
chain(*nested_iterables).each do |it|
  puts it
end
```

Both output:

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "6", ["eight", "nine", "ten"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
def chain(*aaa)
  aaa.each { |aa| (aa.class == String ? aa.split(//) : aa).each { |a| yield a } }
end
```

Example

```
chain([0, 1], (2..3), [[4, 5]], {6 => 7, 8 => 9}, 'abc') { |e| print e, ',' }
```

Output

```
0,1,2,3,[4, 5],[6, 7],[8, 9],a,b,c,
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby 2.6 Enumerables have a [chain](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-chain) method. It does not split up strings in characters.