# Ruby equivalent to Python chain()

Tags: python, arrays, ruby, language-comparisons

What is the Ruby equivalent of the chain iterator in python?

```
data_chained = []
data2 = {}     
data_chained = chain(data_chained, data2)
```

How can this be done in Ruby?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the Ruby equivalent of Python \`itertools.chain\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919677/whats-the-ruby-equivalent-of-python-itertools-chain)

Comment: Are you referring to `itertools.chain`? That operates on iterables; using it on dictionaries is kind of... weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Ruby 2.6: if it is Enumerable, you can [chain](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerator/Chain.html#method-c-new) it: (example from the docs, chaining a Range to an Array)

```
e = Enumerator::Chain.new(1..3, [4, 5]) 
e.to_a #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
e.size #=> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

[Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.5/Hash.html#method-i-merge)

You use it like below:

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
h1.merge(h2)   #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>254, "c"=>300}
h1.merge(h2){|key, oldval, newval| newval - oldval}
       #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>54,  "c"=>300}
h1             #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
```

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the issue, it may be the same as itertools.chain in python.
This worked for me ->

```
Enumerator::Chain.new(data_chained, data2)
```